# Excel startup prompt setting not working

Tags: excel, reference

I have created an external reference in workbook, the target workbook being hosted on a network folder.
I have set the startup prompt to automatically update the link without notification for the user.

[image]

Despite this, I keep getting the error message[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AFndM.png):

[image]

Where is this failing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the shared folder needs to be open in order to enable automatic update. 
Not practical for my scope, so I changed the approach.